# Connection refused while using Laravel Scout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout

I'm trying to install Laravel Scout into my project. I've follow the documentation :

I've done the `composer require laravel/scout`
Then `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"`
And then `composer require meilisearch/meilisearch-php http-interop/http-factory-guzzle`.

I've also added the  `use Searchable;` to my model and this to the .env file :`SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:7700 MEILISEARCH_KEY=masterKey`

When I'm trying to do `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\Thread"`, I've got this error :
`cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7700: Connection refused`

Do I miss something please ? :/

I'm using xampp.

Comment: Hi! Do you actually have an instance of MeiliSearch running?  https://docs.meilisearch.com/learn/getting_started/installation.html#download-and-launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to launch MeiliSearch. There's this tutorial that explains how to use Laravel Scout with MeiliSearch, step by step: https://postsrc.com/posts/make-your-laravel-search-smarter-with-laravel-scout-and-meilisearch